# How to enable docker Experimental mode on EC2 instance of Windows-Server-2019-Base-with-Containers?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, windows-server

I'm trying to `docker pull postgres` but get this error message instead **no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries**

Which lead me to this solution [How can I run Docker in a AWS Windows Server environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248193/how-can-i-run-docker-in-a-aws-windows-server-environment)

The solution is to enable Experimental mode

But there is no docker icon on my environment.
So I tried to use this command 
`dockerd --experimental`

But got this error
`PS C:\Users\Administrator> dockerd --experimental
time="2019-01-21T08:45:51Z" level=warning msg="Running experimental build"
open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied.`

So how can I enable the experimental mode? 
or are there other solution to avoid the **no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries** problem?

Comment: Indeed, i even went as far as installing Docker Desktop just so that I could find the "experimental" checkbox that everyone was talking about but after checking the checkbox, it's still reporting `Experimental: False` when typing `docker version` on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by using i3.metal (bare metal) instance instead.
This instance quite costly so I would love to hear other solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Docker and dockerd are related.
You have to stop Docker before starting dockerd again.

```
stop-service *docker*
```

Then you can launch your command again

```
dockerd --experimental
```

Notice that this will block the shell because the deamon run where you launch it