# How can I run Docker Desktop in an AWS EC2 Windows server environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2019

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248193/how-can-i-run-docker-in-a-aws-windows-server-environment) from 2017.

Is it possible to run Docker Desktop from an AWS EC2 Windows server environment? Docker Desktop crash upon startup with the following error:

`The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 7A6D9FC6-1F84-450F-983C-C798BB55F8B7).`

Running an AWS EC2 windows server with containers gives the following error when opening Docker Desktop:

`Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro: exit code: -1`

If not, is it possible to run a docker container as well some other script/application (e.g python script) simultaneously on a single Ubuntu or Linux EC2 instance?

Comment: Is this question any different from the one you link to?  Can you just get a Linux EC2 instance and run native Docker there?  Does this question involve writing code at all, or just deploying things in a cloud environment?

Comment: @DavidMaze It is the same problem, only from what I can see and have tried the suggested solutions doesn't work. Running an EC2 Windows server with containers still doesn't allow me to run docker desktop. Am I missing something?